# Is this random forest overfitted?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am training RandomForestRegressor from the scikit-learn library on temporal data and want the forest to predict the trend (next 4 points) given date and time as features.

I am predicting the data in small intervals (4 datapoints) and trying to reconstruct the whole day trend to compare to the actual values and calculate MSE by slicing the dataset

As you can see on the graph below (the first one), predicted line has some patches that are very similar to the actual data line. The only problem is that those similar patches are ahead in time in comparison to the actual line (marked in black circles on the graph)

Does this mean that the model has learned the training data and just spits out the last values it remembered? I have not done any model tunning, only data collection and evaluation of the results for now

Added graph without black markings so it is easier to see the lines

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have edited the prediction as I was afraid there was a bug in the code that produced previous graphs

As suggested by @vpekar in the comments, I have **a) compared MSEs** after the out-of-sample and in-sample evaluations. Median MSE after the ten out-of-sample evaluations is 4.14e-08, while median MSE after the ten in-sample evaluations is 5.30e-08. Figure 3 shows how both results looked like more or less. 
[image: Figure 1] Figure 3

All the evaluation has been done with a standard non-tuned model

```
`RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10000, criterion='mse', max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1,max_features=5, max_leaf_nodes=None, bootstrap=False, oob_score=False, n_jobs=1, verbose=0, warm_start=False)`
```

After that I ran **b) random search** for model parameters and got the best results (Figure 4) on the out-of-sample evaluation 6.3e-06 (100 times worse than the MSE of the default model) with the following parameters:

```
bootstrap=False, criterion=mse, max_depth=35, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=60, min_impurity_decrease=0 min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=74, min_samples_split=64, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0 n_estimators=10000, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False
```

[image]Figure 4

Question: Does this mean that the default RandomForestRegressor parameters lead to an overfitted model in the case of my data? (Figure 3)

Comment: You can detect overfitting by comparing MSE on the training/in-sample set vs. MSE on the test/out-of-sample set. if MSE is much lower on the train, there is overfitting. To see if your model does better than simply outputting the previous day's value as the forecast, you can implement a baseline that actually does that, and then compare its MSE to that of your model.

Comment: @vpekar and what if the MSEs of both in-sample and out-of-sample are similar? I have added more test results to my question

Comment: If the performance measures in the training and test set are similar, there is no overfitting.