# sklearn random forest search for model parameters for a model that will predict continuous temporal variables

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, temporal-database

I am trying to predict the best parameters for the random forest RandomizedSearchCV that is supposed to predict a continuous varible.

I've been looking at the following approach, in particular, changing *scoring* function and eventually settling for regression logistic function *median_absolute_error*. However, I think that the *KFold* cross-validation is not appropriate for my data, but I do not understand how I can, for example, use an *iterable cv* (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) as I can not run (as far as I understand) *fit* and *predict* on my model before the *RandomizedSearchCV*

```
def my_custom_score(y_true, y_pred, dates_, features, labels):
    return median_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)

...
for i in range(0, 3): #predict 3 10-point intervals
    prediction_colour = ['g','r','c','m','y','k','w'][i%7]

    date_for_test = randint(11, 200) #end of the trend
    dates_for_test = range(date_for_test-10, date_for_test) #one predicted interval should have 10 date points

    for idx, date_for_test_ in enumerate(sorted(dates_for_test, reverse=True)):
        train_features = features[sorted(dates_for_test, reverse=True)[0]-2:]
        train_labels = labels[sorted(dates_for_test, reverse=True)[0]-2:]
        test_features = np.atleast_2d(features[date_for_test_])
        test_labels = labels[date_for_test_] if date_for_test != 0 else 1.0

        rf = RanzomForestRegressor(bootstrap=False, criterion='mse', max_features=5, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
        parameters = {"max_leaf_nodes": [2,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50], "min_samples_leaf": [1,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000], "min_samples_split": [2,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000], 'n_estimators': [10, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000, 2250, 2500, 2750, 3000, 3250, 3500, 3750, 4000, 4250, 4500, 4750, 5000, 5250, 5500, 5750, 6000, 6250, 6500, 6750, 7000, 7250, 7500, 7750, 8000, 8250, 8500, 8750, 9000, 9250, 9500, 9750, 10000], 'max_depth':[1,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]}
        grid_search = RandomizedSearchCV(cv=5, estimator=rf, param_distributions=parameters, n_iter=10, scoring=make_scorer(median_absolute_error))#, scoring=make_scorer(lambda x,y: my_custom_score(x, y, sorted(dates_for_test, reverse=True), features, labels), greater_is_better=False)))

        grid_search.fit(train_features, train_labels)

        rf = grid_search.best_estimator_
        best_parameters=rf.get_params()
        print ("best parameters")
        for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
            print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))

        predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
```

Also, with the current approach I get the same continuous value predicted on out-of-sample temporal data of few dates into the future (different colours on the graph):

[image]

Documentation is quite detailed on this matter, but I find it too detailed. I just get lost there. Maybe someone could point in the right direction?

Comment: What is your question? Can you please be more precise as in what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @gorjan what is the right way to search for the parameters for random forests that are expected to predict continuous temporal variable?

Comment: @BorisMocialov Neither Random Forests nor Parameter Search deal with continuous temporal variables. They expect data in the usual tabular form of `observations * features` and `labels`/`target`. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you show, except for formatting and typos. If you do not get the expected results, most likely there is a mistake in how you represent the temporal data in tabular form.

Comment: @kazemakase RandomForestRegressor does a great job at predicting future out-of-sample continuous temporal values Figure3 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389360/is-this-random-forest-overfitted), unfortunately I am not able to control parameters as majority are set to 'None'. RandomizedSearchCV has cv parameter that allows custom train, test splits (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) and also LeavePOut model selection option, which sounds perfect for predicting continuous data. I have gone through features and they all look fine

Comment: What kind of of problem do you have with a `cv` param? It's an iterable of (train,test) tuples, like [(train1,test1),(train2,test2), ...]

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov To get test, I will have to run fit and predict before RandomizedSearchCV, which sounds very counterintuitive. RandomizedSearchCV asks for estimator, which I assume is used to predict test list/iterator (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L66)

Comment: I suspect you need to structure your problem correctly. First, divide your data in train(past)/test(future) subperiods, define features, pick up estimator (RF or XGB), define parameter space, and finally run `RandomizedSearchCV` to choose best set of hyperparams.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I have edited the code adding processing of the data. The snippet has been verified multiple times to make sure it is correct. The training data is everything from the start until some randomly chosen point, the test data is len(training_data)-3:len(training_data)+7 if the out-of-sample setting. What is XGB? I cannot find it in the documentation. If scoring=make_scorer(lambda x,y: my_custom_score(x, y,..)) is chosen, then it is obvious that the y (test) is what is predicted, so I am not sure how dividing the data helps. This should be the output from the predict procedure

Comment: What you're doing is more complex than I suggested but acceptable. However, the real problem is that your estimator does not learn. You need to find a reason why. I have 2 bets: either  you messed up the target values  or you have too little data. To find out out if this problem amenable to RF estimator, I would start with the simplest possible case: divide the whole dataset into train(past)/test(future), say 150/50 datapoints; then, train manually on train and validate on test. See if this results in more meaningful predictions.